# How to incorporate multiple objects of json array into react component

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I would like to iterate over this json string and input the values into a react component: `{"users":[{"name":"jkhhjjh","url":"/users/240/individual_show"},{"name":"bob","url":"/users/241/individual_show"}]}`

I can currently make one component from the first or second object within the json index but I cannot iterate over the whole string. My react-jsx code is below:
`enter code here`

```js
 var FriendInfo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      url: '',
      name: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get(this.props.source, function(user) {
      var users= user["users"][0];
      if (this.isMounted()) {
        this.setState({url: users.url,
           url: users.url,
           name: users.name
        });
      }
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="friendInfo">
              <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/SRC-TV.svg/140px-SRC-TV.svg.png"></img>
              <a href={this.state.url}>{this.state.name}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var RequestLinks= React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="requestLinks" style={{float:"right"}}>
        <a href="accept.com">accept</a>
        <a href="deny.com">deny</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var FriendBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="friendBox">
        <FriendInfo source="/individual_relationships/show"/>
        <RequestLinks />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render(<FriendBox />,  document.getElementById('test'));`enter code here`
```

After the line `var users= user["users"][0]` I am able to insert the data into one iteration of the component. I would like to make a loop that would iterate over `user["users"][0]` and `user["users"][1]` to make two components on the page. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of map function which returns array of indivisual elements.

```js
var FriendInfo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
return {
  users: []
};
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
$.get(this.props.source, function (user) {
  var users = user["users"];
  if (this.isMounted()) {
    this.setState({users: users});
  }
}.bind(this));
  },

  render: function () {
return (
  <div>
{
  this.state.users.map(function (user) {

return <div className="friendInfo">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/SRC-TV.svg/140px-SRC-TV.svg.png"></img>
  <a href={user.url}>{user.name}</a>
</div>
  })
  
  }
  </div>
);
  }
});

var RequestLinks = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
return (
  <div className="requestLinks" style={{float: "right"}}>
    <a href="accept.com">accept</a>
    <a href="deny.com">deny</a>
  </div>
);
  }
});

var FriendBox = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
return (
  <div className="friendBox">
    <FriendInfo source="/individual_relationships/show"/>
    <RequestLinks />
  </div>
);
  }
});
React.render(<FriendBox />, document.getElementById('test'));
```